# node.js> express multiport for security! possible?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a node.js server using the.

For security reasons, I will be make the something(ssl, tsl, tunnerling)

So access to the server port to distinguish it? 
ex) 
3000port -> `ssl` 
 
3001port -> `tls` 
3002port -> `tunnerling`

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, your `app` object that you get from calling `express()` can used as a `request` event handler for the built-in http/https server. Add it to however many servers you have/need:

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});

https.createServer({ ... }, app).listen(3000);
https.createServer({ ... }, app).listen(3001);
```

However I'm not sure why you want to have separate SSL and TLS-based HTTPS servers. It's best to avoid SSL anyway, but you should be able to use both SSL and TLS on the same server instance.

Comment: I thought. SSL1.0 -> SSL2.0 -> SSL3.0 -> TLS1.0 |
SSL3.0 = TLS 1.0  Is this correct? 
So I need to distinguish between SSL and TLS not? 
Just TLS!?